# Can white collar crime cases be settled out of court?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, settlement, mediation

I'm a victim of wire fraud (email fraud).

A company successfully obtained some confidential information from me using social engineering methods.

The company now aware that I have a strong evidences against them that is enough to put them in jail. The information they obtained from me is worth a lot of value in their hands.

I believe civil matters can be settled via Alternative Dispute Resolution (ADR). But since my issue involves criminal laws, can white collar crime matters like this be settled via ADR (mediation)?

It is my understanding, a faster amicable resolution can be reached when the matter settled outside court. I also don't want to damage their company's reputation by pursuing a public litigation and wasting money on that.

So, can white collar crime matters like this be settled outside court? What are the drawbacks of settling matters like this outside court?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you concerned about their reputation? If they committed fraud, they *should* have a bad reputation. Trying to protect their reputation will just make it easier for them to do the same thing to other victims.

Comment: @Someone You have a valid point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fraud is simultaneously a civil wrong (a.k.a. a "tort") and a criminal violation. The civil wrong can be settled out of court. Relief from a criminal violation can be obtained only from the prosecutor and it is not proper to include an agreement not to press criminal charges in a settlement of a civil case.

Comment: “Not proper” meaning illegal.

Comment: @DaleM "Not proper" means violating professional ethics.

Comment: no, what you describe, a quid pro quo of not reporting a crime in return for some benefit is straight up extortion